# How can I use regex to match a string without double characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a block of text that I want to run some regex on in javascript, to match `[code]`. I know I can use `/\[code\]/g` to do this.

However, I want to ignore cases where double brackets are used, as in`[[code]]`. So in other words, in the string `[code] [[code]] [code]`, only the first and last occurrences should match.

Is this possible?

http://regexr.com/395kr

Comment: I also used a negative look ahead: http://regexr.com/395l1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS does not support negative lookbehind assertions, but seems like the negative lookahead is enough in your case:

```
'[code] [[code]] [code]'.match(/\[code\](?!\])/g)
```

This regex ensures that the next character after matched `[code]` is not a `]`

**UPD**:

It could be improved to

```
'[code] [[code]] [code]'.match(/\[(?!\[)code\](?!\])/g)
```

thanks to Felix Kling.

A note: it will behave weird in case of unpaired braces.

Comment: You could also add `\[(?!\[)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` for this:

```
var data = "[code] [[code]] [code]";
data = data.match(/\[+code\]+/g) // gives us ["[code]", "[[code]]", "[code]"]
    .filter(function(x) { return !x.match(/\[\[code\]\]/); });
// data is now ["[code]", "[code]"]
```

Felix's method also works nicely.